# Android put button on surfaceview at runtime to capture image

Tags: android, button, camera, surfaceview

i'm new to android i've created one camera app from scratch in here i have surfaceview created at run time i want to create one button above it how can i do it???

here is my code camera is showing perfectly want to add one button above it to capture image

```
package com.example.urvey.tool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.lang.*;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.text.Layout;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;



@SuppressLint({ "SdCardPath", "NewApi" }) public class Camera_screen extends Activity {
    //AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
       Preview P = new Preview(this);
    setContentView(P);

        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Press Me");
System.out.println("halyu");
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.cam_out);
        layout.addView(myButton);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_camera, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        Camera mCamera;



        public Preview(Context context) {

            super(context);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = this.getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            System.out.println("constructor");
            }


        @SuppressLint({ "SdCardPath", "SdCardPath" }) public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
            // to draw.

            try {

                 mCamera = Camera.open();
               mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;



                // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
            // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
            // important to release it when the activity is paused.
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        public void previewCamera()
        {        
            try 
            {           
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);          
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi") public Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters){
            Camera.Size bestSize = null;
            List<Camera.Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

            bestSize = sizeList.get(0);

            for(int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++){
             if((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) >
               (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)){
              bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
             }
            }

            return bestSize;
           }



        @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.



                 Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                 Camera.Size myBestSize = getBestPreviewSize(3, 4, parameters);
              /* List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Size   size = sizes.get(0);*/
                if(myBestSize != null){
                 mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    parameters.setPreviewSize(myBestSize.width, myBestSize.height);
                    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
              }






                mCamera.startPreview();



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Is your `myButton` the button you're asking about? If so, is it giving you an error or not showing?

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with your `setContentView()`, I'm assuming that the `RelativeLayout layout` you add the button to is in the `activity_camera` layout but you change the `setContentView()` to `Preview`. Comment out that line and run your app to see if it is showing. Also, if the button is constant then you don't necessarily need to build it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as a substitute for your `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    // Preview P = new Preview(this);
    // setContentView(P);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Press Me");
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.cam_out);
    layout.addView(myButton);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("onClick", "myButton");
    // Process the Image, etc
}
```